# How may I suppress the pslist (un)welcome lines?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, sysinternals

How may I suppress the pslist (un)welcome text lines seen  here?

[image: http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img745/8431/1JOlN5.png]

2>NUL need not apply, since I want error output not suppressed.

Comment: As a workaround you might use the built-in [`tasklist`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730909.aspx) utility instead.

Comment: "Which lines don't you want?" All of those.

Comment: "As a workaround you might use the built-in tasklist utility instead" Thanks, but I see no equivalent of pslist -e there.

Comment: @ChrisJJ What about `tasklist /fi "imagename eq whatever.exe"` ?

Comment: Thanks, but it fails to set errorlevel.

Comment: Maybe you could show us what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe there are other ways. You could use find or findstr (which does return an errorlevel). For instance... this would give an errorlevel: `tasklist /fi "imagename eq whatever.exe" | find "whatever.exe"  1>nul`

Comment: "Maybe you could show us what you're trying to accomplish" Simply set errorlevel to indicate whether a named process exists.

Comment: Ok, for that... this command will do: `tasklist /fi "imagename eq whatever.exe" | find "whatever.exe" 1>nul`

Comment: @Rik. Thanks. That works fine here, and has the advantage over pskill of using only in-built commands. However I do note that the errorlevel effect of find is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ChrisJJ What do you mean "undefined behaviour"? Although there is no mention of it on [the man page for Find](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725655.aspx) the command is listed on the page which commands return Errorlevels [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/81819).

Comment: @Rik. I mean behaviour that is undefined. " the command is listed on the page which commands return Errorlevels here." Thanks for the correction.